# How can I program in HTML to show an image at a specific time of the day?

Tags: html

I have been researching and studying various HTML code with similar questions but wanted to try something a little different: (And please forgive me for my silly sounding questions here. I am still quite new with this kinds of things so still experimenting with a lot)

1) I want to know if it's possible to write code in HTML that will allow the display of an image at a certain time. Like let's say for example, the image will only appear at midnight local time from wherever someone is searching.

2) If this is possible, how to I first display one image on a website and then at a specified time have that image replaced by a different image and then after let's say one minute everything will revert back to the original image on the website?

3) How do I "store" the image I want to have displayed at a certain time of the day? I mean, how do I program in HTML to show that new image but obviously not make it possible to be known in the source code?

4) Last, is it possible to prevent proxy servers from being used or other means that could potentially manipulate the time.

Thank you much!

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/time2.shtml

Comment: 1. Not with html only. You need [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for this. 2. Yes. Using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or setTimeout. 3. Make an ajax call to retrieve the image url so it won't be part of the source code. 4. I believe not

Comment: You need javascript to do something like that. And for questions 3 and 4, you'll need to have a server that send the image to display. That's the only way to be sure your image is not 'found' by looking at the source code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answers! I will look over these links and see if I can make sense of them! :)